# How to count occurrences of string in numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy

So I have changed my previous code

```
if advice[i] == real_choice[i]:
        correct[i] = "CORRECT"
      else:
        correct[i] =  "INCORRECT"
```

to

```
correct = np.where( advice == real_choice, "CORRECT", "INCORRECT")
```

but now my code after this, that calculates the number of occurrences of the string `"INCORRECT"` in `correct`, no longer works:

```
num_incorrect = correct.str.count("INCORRECT").sum()
```

how can I do the above line in a way that is compatible with the new method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where` returns a numpy array, not a pandas series. So you want:

```
(correct=='INCORRECT').sum()
```

Comment: That works, and it actually made me realize that it was indeed very simple and I was doing something else wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```py
# numpy array
(correct == "INCORRECT").sum()

dict(zip(*np.unique(correct, return_counts=True)))["INCORRECT"]

# list
list(correct).count("INCORRECT")
```

or

```py
correct = np.where( advice[i] == real_choice[i], 1, 0)

incorrect_size = correct.size - correct.sum()
```